# Build error on running ReactJS application

Tags: reactjs, react-native

From package.json file

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "startupjs build",
    "server": "startupjs server",
    "start-production": "startupjs start-production",
    "start": "\"npm run server\" \"npm run web\"",
    "test": "jest",
    "precommit": "lint-staged",
    "web": "startupjs web"
  },
```

we try to run build command i.e. NPM RUN BUILD  we are getting below error message.

> startupjs build 'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file. (node:9184)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Command failed with exit code
>   2 (ENOENT): rm -rf ./build && webpack --config
>   webpack.server.config.js && webpack --config webpack.web.config.js
>   spawn rm ENOENT

Comment: Was it developed on linux? And you're trying to build on which OS?

Comment: Yes it is developed on Linux. we are trying to run it on windows 2012 R2

Comment: there's your problem, windows doesn't have `rm` command in the terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the problem here is that `startupjs` was only designed to run on *nix environments. I would see if [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) can run on your machines and if so, run your `npm` scripts using `bash`.

Alternate solutions: [yarn 2](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install) is designed to prevent these platform-specific problems, or if you can figure out how to use [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs) as your shell, `startupjs` would work.